# triggering a Jquery function when condition is true

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger a Jquery fuction when the result of an "if" statement is true.

I have tried all sorts of ways with no success. I am using "Jbox" by Stephan Wagner which I have used many time without any issues so I think it must be the code I have written.

My code

```
var PassSet = '<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['passwordchange'];?>';
if(PassSet == 0) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var memberid = '<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['member_id'];?>';
        new jBox('Modal', {
            width: 350,
            height: 250,
            title: 'FlightX: Ack Alert',
            theme: 'TooltipBorder',
            closeButton: 'title',
            draggable: 'title',
            //trigger: 'click',
            animation: 'false',

            position: {
                x: 'center',
                y: 'center'
            },

            onCloseComplete: function() {
                this.destroy();
                $('#jBox-overlay').remove();
            },

            ajax: {
                url: 'flightx_change_password.php?UserID=' + memberid,
                reload: 'strict'
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: maybe `typeof(PassSet) == 'undefined'`

Comment: @Ab Sin Hi, the console does not show any erros and PassSet is populate with "0".

Comment: And in debug mode the `if(PassSet==0){console.log(1)}else{console.log(2)}` prints 1?

Comment: @Ab Sin the result is 1

Comment: If PassSet is 1, wouldn't the condition always fail? if (PassSet == 0) would fail if PassSet is 1... or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Paurian Hi, using if(PassSet==0){console.log(1)}else{console.log(2)} the console displays "1" because PassSet = 0. We were just testing the PassSet content.

Comment: You have an extra comma after `y: 'center',` in your `position: { ... }` property/object.

Comment: @Santi Thanks removed "," still does not work.

Comment: So what is the actual *issue*? What are you expecting to happen, and what actually *is* happening?  Your question currently reads as "This doesn't work", which really isn't a whole lot for us to go on.

Comment: Hi, I am expecting the function to call the Ajax url which is a pop up window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(document).ready()` handler is misplaced.

That is an handler "waiting" for the event that occurs when the document is fully loaded (except images) so that the DOM elements are all present and the script can run.

So the idea is to place the value (the `var PassSet`) and the condition within that ready handler.

Now, the value passed by the PHP `echo` **should not** be wrapped with quotes. That makes it a string... Better pass it as an integer.

**EDIT**
If you want to use Ajax to load the content of the modal and open it, here is how I would try to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var PassSet = <?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['passwordchange'];?>;  // Integer here! No quotes.

  // Check the value in console:
  console.log(PassSet);
  console.log(typeof(PassSet));  // Should give "number" in console.

  if(PassSet == 0) {

    var memberid = '<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['member_id'];?>';

    $.ajax({
      url: 'flightx_change_password.php',
      method: 'post',
      data:{UserID: memberid},
      success: function(response){

        new jBox('Modal', {
          width: 350,
          height: 250,
          title: 'FlightX: Ack Alert',
          theme: 'TooltipBorder',
          closeButton: 'title',
          draggable: 'title',
          //trigger: 'click',
          animation: 'false',

          content: response // Response from the Ajax request

          position: {
              x: 'center',
              y: 'center'
          },

          onCloseComplete: function() {
              this.destroy();
              $('#jBox-overlay').remove();
          }
        })
      }

    });

  }
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. I have changed the code as per your answer, the console shows "0" and "number" as expected but the popup wondows does not open. The script called by the Ajax call is present in the same directory and works if I access it directly.

Comment: And are you sure that jBox has an `ajax` property? I don't see it in a quick overview of the [documentation](https://github.com/StephanWagner/jBox). So you want to call the modal conntent using Ajax, right?

Comment: I edited my answer with a better use of Ajax... Have a look.